# Как отсортировать числа в выпадающем списке?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Вставляю скриптом в гугл шитс выпадающий список. Выпадающий список состоит из чисел от 1 и до 100. При этом в списке они сортируются как текст => очень неудобно выбирать. Как их можно отсортировать как числа от меньшего к большему?

```
 var pages_list = []
  var  page = 1  
  while (page <= insertparams['pages_count']) {
    pages_list.push(page); 
    page++;
  }
  var cell = Sheet.getRange('page_number')  
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(pages_list).build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
```

Comment: Поменять тип ячейки на число

Comment: Спасибо! Оказалось все просто, достаточно было поменять тип ячейки на число. Приведенный код - рабочий.

Comment: К сожалению, мне не удалось повторить проблему. Чего-то не хватает в описании. При любом формате данных ячеек я получаю тот порядок, который задан списком. Тип ячеек никак не влияет на валидацию данных. Т.е. работает как надо. Что я делаю не так? https://bitbucket.org/snippets/contributorpw/LrGgAb

Comment: "мне не удалось повторить проблему" - я формировал список из скрипта, скрипт добавил в вопрос. Возможно, ранее формта ячейки был текстовый или еще какой-то

Comment: Ага, т.е. повторить это нельзя. Т.е. решение не в этом.